# VB (Excel) запись в ячейку по индексу строки и имени колонки

Tags: visual-basic

пишу скрипт на VB  (Excel), подскажите как записать данные в ячейку имея имя колонки и номер строки.
Спасибо.

Comment: Что подразумевается под именем: название столбца (A, B, AF)? название в заголовке таблицы? имя, присвоенное диапазону? Покажите пример. И метка, похоже, не та. VB и  VBA - не одно и то же

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name

**Запишет в ячейку "B10" значение "27"**

```
Range("B" & 10).Value = 27
```

**Либо так**

```
ColName = "B"
RowNumber = "10"
Range(ColName & RowNumber).Value = 27
```

**Можно еще через Cells**

```
ColName = "B"
RowNumber = "10"
Cells(RowNumber, Range(ColName & 1).Column).Value = 27
```

Comment: я не так сформулировал вопрос. Имею ввиду, что есть колонка с именами, например Names и номер строки

Comment: @Germes1989 понятнее не стало. добавь описание в вопрос с примером таблицы и результатом